# Python UDP Server send lines of a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sockets

I need to simulate a UDP server, which sends content of a text file line by line in an endless loop. I have written the code below but at the other end I do not receive anything (The other side is Qt code and I am sure it works):

```
import socket
import time

# setup UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sa = ('localhost', 9763)
sock.bind(sa)

filename = '/home/saeid/Documents/data.txt'  # file to read
numlines = sum(1 for line in open(filename))  # get number of lines in file


# get line of a file
def get_line(line):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for i, l in enumerate(fp):
            if i == line:
                return l

# main loop
while True:
    currline = 0
    while currline < numlines:
        sock.sendto(get_line(currline), sa)
        currline += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

I am no python pro and cant figure out the problem :(

Comment: aside: your way of reading the file is just terrible...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yep...as I said I am no python code, I just need a quick and dirty UDP socket to work :(

Comment: to send to someone you need its IP and Port. You bind to `('localhost', 9763)` and later you send to `('localhost', 9763)` so you send to yourself, not to other program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters this is messed up:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sa = ('localhost', 9763)
sock.bind(sa)
...
sock.sendto(get_line(currline), sa)
```

By binding you basically say "I want to listen on that host/port". But then you send the data to the same host/port. I assume that there's some other destination address, e.g. `sock.sendto(get_line(currline), ('my_host', 1234))`. By the way, why are you binding to the address anyway? `sock.bind(sa)` line is unnecessary, remove it.

---

The other thing is that your file reading code is extremely inefficient and difficult to read (it took me a while to understand what's going on). Try something like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fo:
    while True:
        for line in fo:
            sock.sendto(line, DEST_ADDRESS)
            time.sleep(1)
        fo.seek(0)  # go back to the begining of the file and repeat
```

and get rid of `get_line` function.

That's at least what I've came up with after reading your description. If you don't want to inifinitely send the same file then you can get rid of `while True:` loop and `fo.seek(0)` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are a life saver :D

Answer (score 1):

Uncle google came up with [User Datagram Client and Server](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/udp.html)

**User Datagram Client and Server**

The user datagram protocol (UDP) works differently from TCP/IP. Where TCP is a stream oriented protocol, ensuring that all of the data is transmitted in the right order, UDP is a message oriented protocol. UDP does not require a long-lived connection, so setting up a UDP socket is a little simpler. On the other hand, UDP messages must fit within a single packet (for IPv4, that means they can only hold 65,507 bytes because the 65,535 byte packet also includes header information) and delivery is not guaranteed as it is with TCP.

**Echo Server**

Since there is no connection, per se, the server does not need to listen for and accept connections. It only needs to use bind() to associate its socket with a port, and then wait for individual messages.

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
```

Messages are read from the socket using recvfrom(), which returns the data as well as the address of the client from which it was sent.

```
while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

    print >>sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address)
    print >>sys.stderr, data

    if data:
        sent = sock.sendto(data, address)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sent %s bytes back to %s' % (sent, address)
```

**Echo Client**

The UDP echo client is similar the server, but does not use bind() to attach its socket to an address. It uses sendto() to deliver its message directly to the server, and recvfrom() to receive the response.

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'

try:

    # Send data
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)

    # Receive response
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive'
    data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

**Client and Server Together**

Running the server produces:

```
$ python ./socket_echo_server_dgram.py

starting up on localhost port 10000

waiting to receive message
received 42 bytes from ('127.0.0.1', 50139)
This is the message.  It will be repeated.
sent 42 bytes back to ('127.0.0.1', 50139)

waiting to receive message
```

and the client output is:

```
$ python ./socket_echo_client_dgram.py

sending "This is the message.  It will be repeated."
waiting to receive
received "This is the message.  It will be repeated."
closing socket

$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the destination address or port in your call to `sendto`:

```
        peer_address = ('localhost', peer_port)
        sock.sendto(get_line(currline), peer_address)
```

To which address and port does the Qt application bind?

Comment: to the same port, 9763

Comment: @SaeidYazdani Then the host must be different. 2 different applications cannot bind to the same `(host, port)` pair. The OS won't allow it.